# What would be a naming element convention to distinguish between different carbon-based life forms?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, aliens, alternate-worlds, chemistry

I have an alien race that is carbon-based, like life on Earth, but this alien life uses different essential elements in their biochemistry than those elements used on Earth.

I'm trying to come up with a a naming element convention that the aliens might use that allows them to uniquely distinguishes between our (Earth-based) carbon-based life and their alien carbon-based life.

For example, suppose that the aliens contain hydrogen, carbon, oxygen, but not nitrogen. Hypothetically, these aliens dub life on Earth as nitrogen-unique life forms.  (This is one example, but I'm wondering if there is something a little more scientific or concrete.)

What is a naming element convention that distinguishes different forms of life based on the unique essential elements in their biochemistries?

Comment: Sounds perfectly cogent to me. Besides, an alien race would most certainly view humanity as distinctly different, much like we distinguish between ourselves and other animals...

Comment: Interestingly enough sugar does not contain nitrogen.

Comment: What do you mean by :atomic count"?

Comment: @HDE226868 I think he might mean the number of electrons orbiting the nucleus.

Comment: @DustinJackson I thought it was either that, atomic number, or the percentage of atoms in the body. The problem is, nitrogen has a *greater* atomic number (and thus, in its neutral state, a greater number of electrons in the electron cloud).

Comment: I see potential in the question, it's just not well-worded.

Comment: If I recall my chemistry lessons well, there was a reason why carbon was ideal for organic-based compounds, and it had to do mostly with its ability to easily add or subtract electrons in order to make it stable.  Nitrogen needs 3 electrons or it can lose 5, though it tends to pull 3 electrons more than it adds 5.  Usually you talk about silicon-based life forms because it, like carbon, can add or subtract 4 electrons.  However this is just a pedantic point.

Comment: While nitrogen is important, it's not the base. Consider all the trace elements required for (at least mammalian) life - iron, copper, zinc, potassium, sodium, chlorine - oh, there's a good one: can we be described as chlorine-based? Nitrogen is not a viable base because free nitrogen winds up bound in (among other things) N2, and it takes a whole lot of energy to make it  available.

Comment: To expand on @WhatRoughBeast said... Nitrogen is a crappy base for life. It forms too powerful of bonds, does not tend to form branching molecular chains (which are necessary for the complexity of life), and is a gas in its native form...meaning it must be maintained in molecular compounds at all times while held within the body.

Comment: The edit to the question still leaves quite a lot to be desired. 'Nitrogen-essential' is horribly non-specific. Because we are also hydrogen-essential, oxygen-essential, phosphorous-essential, iron-essential, and so on. Heck...if we only count the materials contained in DNA: Carbon, Nitrogen, Hydrogen, and Oxygen, with Carbon being dominant in terms of frequency

Comment: Wow, this is hard to formulate.

Comment: This could just be me, but I still don't understand the question.

Comment: I'm going to try to aggressively edit the question to make it a little more cogent.  @linuxfreebird Feel free to change anything you want; my feeling won't be hurt :)

Comment: I finally see what you were getting at. I'll cast the 5th vote to reopen this question.

Comment: Of it's something subtler than non-carbon than one could say non-protein based or using some kind of protein alternative - hydroxyester or sth. it might be rather a question for Biology SE maybe.

Answer (score 11):

Calling something an "X-based life form" (where X is a chemical element) is useful exactly if you are trying to distinguish it from some other life form which is *not* X-based.

If your aliens are thinking of other forms of life which do not use nitrogen, then yes, in principle "nitrogen-based" is a reasonable term to describe us.

Wikipedia has an interesting article on proposed [alternate biochemistry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothetical_types_of_biochemistry) schemas which may be of some use.

Comment: This would be especially useful if there are other races that are carbon-based but not nitrogen-essential.  In that situation "carbon-based" might be inaccurate.

Answer (score 3):

If the question deals with what is essential, rather than what a life-form is based on, then yes, you can certainly call Earth-based life nitrogen-essential. No problem.

But why are your aliens fixated on nitrogen? Let's look at a few other elements that are essential, at least for most species (in order of atomic weight):

Hydrogen

Boron

Oxygen

Sodium

Magnesium

Phosphorus

Sulfur

Chlorine

Potassium

Calcium

Iron

Copper

And I'm sure there are more, but I'm too lazy to think about it.

So, what's so special about nitrogen?

Comment: Is the word 'essential' not specific enough? I am currently struggling to find a better substitute.

Answer (score 2):

They might call earth life as "nitrogen-dependent".

Nitrogenated life. Or something like that.

Lets suppose they use arsenic in most of their lifeforms, we could call them arsenated lifeforms or arsenic-dependent (For us arsenic is quite toxic). This might be reciprocal. But, nitrogen is a too important component of our lives, all proteins contain it.

Its the base of aminoacids. In a aminoacid, a amine group is linked to a carbon compound and this compound is linked to a carboxylic acid group. Without nitrogen theres no aminoacids, without aminoacids you have no proteins and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Nitrogen in humans is essential to amino acids and thus, proteins.  Perhaps the aliens' bodies synthesize their own proteins using phosphorus instead.

[For example](http://www.nature.com/news/arsenic-life-bacterium-prefers-phosphorus-after-all-1.11520)

"Carbos" versus "Phosphoros"

Answer (score 1):

Have the element that is found in highest amounts be what it is called. Though small disconnect with "Carbon-based."

Or maybe "(compound X) based" for highest occurring compound, like h20, you could say we are "Water-based."